# Nesting @media rules in element

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, less

Is it a good practice to nest `@media` rules for each `class` separately or is it better to create `@media` and nest all classes inside?
Which method is more efficient in terms of speed of loading pages?

```
/* 
 * Sass or Less 
 */

/* example_1 */
.class1 {
  width: 100%;

  @media screen and (min-width: 740px) { 
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* example_2 */
.class1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.class2 {
  color: #000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 740px) { 
  .class1 {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .class2 {
    color: #faa;
  }
}
```

Comment: no. @media rules actually wrap around other elements. This should cause an error.

Comment: I use Less preprocessor. This doesn't cause an error.

Comment: Ah. I have not used `LESS`. Probably should. One would think that nesting all the classes inside would be more efficient since the css loads top-bottom and would have to read each rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it depends on the amount of the code you are going to write. It works without any problem, but hundreds of different media queries nested in each class could be hard to maintain. In my opinion a good practice, especially for big projects, would be to use separate files for each media query threshold, in order to keep your CSS organized as much as possible.
For example:

#### style.less

```
.class1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.class2 {
  color: #000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 740px) { 
  @import "min740.less";
}
```

#### min740.less

```
.class1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.class2 {
  color: #faa;
}
```

If you are going to write separate components, like buttons or typographies, you can keep all the related media queries in the same file, in order to have a completely separate CSS module (your 2nd example basically).

In terms of speed and performances, obviously is always recommended to use compiled LESS in production, but considering your examples, the single media query selector would be more efficient, since in the "example1 way" the media query selector will be replicated multiple times:

```
.class1 {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 740px) {
  .class1 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
.class2 {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 740px) {
  .class2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have _"hundreds of different media queries"_ you are doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: But if you have a single media query for each class you can easily reach this number.